# Video Processing frame value can not using in main funtion in OpenCv Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I want to use frame value array which including video loop but I can't get values from video processing function. What I want to do is to take the frame sequence values from the video function, then use those values in the main function. But both the while loop scope and the video function scope do not allow this. I'd appreciate it if you could help. Thank you from now.

```
def video_processing(): 

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

     while True:

      ret, frame = cap.read()

      if ret == True :      

          cv2.imshow("Image", frame)


      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27 :      
          cap.release()
          break

def main():

      video_processing()
      print frame  #is not working!


if __name__ == '__main__':

     main()
```

---

**Update (Full Code)**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from ttk import Frame
import os
import time
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
import cv2
import threading
import time
import imutils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import Thread


Frames = []

def video_processing(): 

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\eren\OneDrive\Desktop\WIN_20190522_18_16_29_Pro.mp4")
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

    global Frames

    while True:
        global Frames
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        y , x = hsv.shape[:2] #x = 320 , y = 240

        # Define 'brown' range in HSV colorspace
        lower = np.array([10, 100, 20])
        upper = np.array([20, 255, 200])

        # Threshold the HSV image to get only brown color
        mask1  = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        thresh = cv2.dilate(mask1,kernel,iterations = 2)

        # find contours in thresholded image, then grab the largest
        # one
        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

        # determine the most extreme points along the contour
        extLeft  = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        extTop   = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        extBot   = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(thresh, extLeft , 8, (0, 0, 255)  , -1)
        cv2.circle(thresh, extRight, 8, (0, 255, 0)  , -1)
        cv2.circle(thresh, extTop  , 8, (255, 0, 0)  , -1)
        cv2.circle(thresh, extBot  , 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)

        x_center = (extLeft[0] + extRight[0] + extTop[0] + extBot[0])/4
        y_center = (extLeft[1] + extRight[1] + extTop[1] + extBot[1])/4

        cv2.circle(frame,(x_center, y_center), 3, (0,255,0), -1)

        cv2.line(frame,(extLeft[0] ,0),(extLeft[0],y) ,(0,255,0),2)               # y axis - binary 
        cv2.line(frame,(extRight[0],0),(extRight[0],y),(0,255,0),2)               # y axis - binary 
        cv2.line(frame,(0,extTop[1])  ,(x,extTop[1])  ,(0,255,0),2)               # x axis - binary 
        cv2.line(frame,(0,extBot[1])  ,(x,extBot[1])  ,(0,255,0),2)               # x axis - binary

        # cv2.imshow("mask" , thresh)
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)

        Frames = frame

        # print frame       
        # return frame

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27 :        
            cap.release()
            break
        # return frame

def main():

    global Frames
    video_processing()

    print Frames
    # print a



if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Why would it work? `frame` is a local variable in the function `video_processing()`.

Comment: I will make GUI and this values need for its. And yes 'frame' is local variable and I am trying to make global variable but I am not getting global variable. Where am I doing wrong? @DanMašek

Comment: Update the code sample to show that attempt to make it a global variable, otherwise it's quite impossible to tell you what's wrong with it. | What sort of GUI? (beside the existing `imshow`)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import cv2

frame = None

def video_processing(): 
    global frame

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('VIDEO_NAME.mp4')

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == True :      
            cv2.imshow("Image", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27 :      
            cap.release()
            break


def main():
      video_processing()
      print(frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```